# Tricky Poisson Distribution question

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

Given that $N～Po(\lambda t)$, where N is the number of customers arrived.
Find the probability that, after t minutes, fewer than 2 customers have
arrived.

The above question requires $Pr(N<2)$ **after t minutes** but not **within t minutes**. 
I am wondering how I should deal with this type of questions. Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "after $t$ minutes?" Are you trying to find, for example, $\lim_{h\downarrow0}\mathbb P(N(t+h)<2)$?

Comment: Generally, that wording is looking for the probability of fewer than $2$ people showing up by the time that $t$ minutes have passed, despite the use of the word "after."  They don't mean the event in which fewer than $2$ people show up after $t$ minutes have already passed.

Comment: got it .thanks for the answer